# Why is the result of debugging different from that of runtime

Tags: python, asynchronous, pycharm, yield

```
def foo():
    print("starting...")
    for n in range(4):
        res = yield 4
        print("res:", res)

g = foo()
for i in g:
    print(i)
```

This is a python program. When I set the breakpoint on line 8, the result is shown as here:

[image]

When the breakpoint is on line 7, the output is different，like this:

[image]

Comment: Which PyCharm version is this? Did you simply resume 4 times in the first case?

Comment: The version is pycharm-community-2019.2.2.exe. I think it's probably where I set it up wrong. Maybe pycharms on other people's computers don't work out.

Comment: What do you mean by "different" ? What do you see in the runtime?

Comment: I've just tried to recreate this with PyCharm professional 2019 2.5 and PyCharm community 2019.1.4 but in all cases I get the output from the second example.